# Format error in table using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I´m using PHPMailer when sending a mail. Before sending the mail, I show the table (`echo $table; die;`) and its shown with no problems. Like this:

[image]

But after, when I send the mail, it is shown with a `<td>` totally wrong:

[image]

The mail send has some text besides the table, and this are the lines that send the mail:

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->AddAddress("mail@domain.com");
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->SetFrom($emailFrom, $name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->Send();
```

Edit:
Also, sometimes this problem does not happen and it is formatted right. And is not the issue of a specific row (201503 is the problem here, I create another mail using only that row and its shown perfectly).

Here the lines that create the table:

```
        $table.= "<br/><table style='margin:auto;' border='1'>";
        $table.="<thead>";
        $table.= "
                <tr>
                    <td align='center' bgcolor='#88CAFF'>
                        <b>Periodo</b>
                    </td>
                    <td align='center' bgcolor='#88CAFF'>
                        <b>Deuda de contribuci&oacute;n</b>
                    </td>
                    <td align='center' bgcolor='#88CAFF'>
                        <b>Inter&eacute;s de contribuci&oacute;n</b>
                    </td>
                    <td align='center' bgcolor='#88CAFF'>
                        <b>Deuda de aporte</b>
                    </td>
                    <td align='center' bgcolor='#88CAFF'>
                        <b>Inter&eacute;s de Aporte</b>
                    </td>
                    <td align='center' bgcolor='#88CAFF'>
                        <b>Total</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>";

        $table.= "<tbody>";

            for ($i=0;$i<=count($resu)-2;$i++)
            {
                        $tmp = $resu[$i];

                        $table.= "<tr>";
                        $table.= "<td>".$tmp['periodo']."</td>";
                        $table.= "<td>$ ".number_format($tmp['montodeuda'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                        $table.= "<td>$ ".number_format($tmp['montointeres'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                        $table.= "<td>$ ".number_format($tmp['montoapo'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                        $table.= "<td>$ ".number_format($tmp['montointapo'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                        $table.= "<td>$ ".number_format($tmp['total'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                        $table.= "</tr>";
            }

                    $table.= "<tr>";
                    $table.= "<td width='%25' bgcolor='#88CAFF'><b>Total a pagar</b></td>";
                    $table.= "<td bgcolor='#88CAFF'>$ ".number_format($resu[count($resu)-1]['montodeuda'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                    $table.= "<td bgcolor='#88CAFF'>$ ".number_format($resu[count($resu)-1]['montointeres'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                    $table.= "<td bgcolor='#88CAFF'>$ ".number_format($resu[count($resu)-1]['montoapo'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                    $table.= "<td bgcolor='#88CAFF'>$ ".number_format($resu[count($resu)-1]['montointapo'],2,',','.')."</td>";
                    $table.= "<td bgcolor='#88CAFF'><b>$ ".number_format($resu[count($resu)-1]['total'],2,',','.')."</b></td>";
                    $table.= "</tr>";

        $table.= "</tbody>";

       $table.= "</table><br/>";
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: I think thats not issue of PHPMailer... its more a syntax error.. when you generate the table...the browser can it render correctly...mail client not

Comment: The problem also is, that sometis it formats wrong and sometimes no. And it's not problem of a specific row. I ll edit now.

Comment: Use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org) to spot what you're doing wrong.